# while Creating classic Dataflow templates For some reason the template is not written to the template_location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For some reason the template is not written to the template_location. When I run the first command, the pipeline is executed (weird) but the template is never generated. What could be the cause?

I am using below cmd to create templet

```bash
python -m my_first_beam.py \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  --project my-project \
  --staging_location gs://gk_beam/staging \
  --temp_location gs://gk_beam/temp \
  --template_location gs://gk_beam/templates/my_first_beam \
  --region europe-west3
```

CMD executing without errors but no templet created in bucket

Comment: So the pipeline is actually executed, but it doesn't take into account that you are trying to call template? Did you follow examples from https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates?

Comment: I followed all steps after executing all steps . i did not see any templet in gcs bucket   python -m examples.mymodule \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project PROJECT_ID \
    --staging_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/staging \
    --temp_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/temp \
    --template_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME \
    --region REGION

Comment: Hi @GopiKiiran, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).